# NGINX on RHEL 8.6 with PHP will not execute a bash shell script through the web server

Tags: php, nginx, rhel

I'm really baffled by this problem! I'm very new to PHP programming so I might be doing something really silly here.

I have NGINX installed on RHEL 8.6 with PHP and I have this very, very basic PHP script. But the 'exec' doesn't run the script no matter what.

Contents of '/usr/share/nginx/test.php':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
  exec('/usr/share/nginx/html/ip.sh 2>&1');
  $myFile = "/tmp/ip.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
  $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
  fclose($fh);
  echo nl2br($theData);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of '/usr/share/nginx/html/ip.sh':

```
#!/bin/sh

ip a > /tmp/ip.txt
chown nginx:nginx /tmp/ip.txt
```

I've triple checked the permissions on the 'test.ph' and 'ip.sh' files are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 nginx nginx   60 Aug 26 08:36 ip.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 nginx nginx  920 Aug 26 10:59 test.php
```

I've also verified that both NGINX and PHP-FPM are running as `nginx:nginx`:

```
root     1507889       1  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx    1507890 1507889  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
nginx    1507891 1507889  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
nginx    1507892 1507889  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
nginx    1507893 1507889  0 10:56 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
```

I've checked to make `SELinux` was not causing any problems:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 nginx nginx unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0   60 Aug 26 08:36 ip.sh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 nginx nginx unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0  920 Aug 26 10:59 test.php
```

I added the following line to /etc/sudoers file:

```
nginx ALL=(user) NOPASSWD: /usr/share/nginx/html/ip.sh
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the script doing? You should check what `exec` gets returned to it, possibly modifying `2>&1` I forget what that does with the execute.

Comment: It runs the 'ip a' shell command which returns output similar to this:

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC ADDRESS> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet X.X.X.X/24 brd X.X.X.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: Why bother with a script at all? Just run the command directly: `$data = passthru('/usr/sbin/ip a');`

Comment: What exactly is the information that you're trying to read? You're probably better off reading directly from the `/proc/net/route` (or similar) meta-file rather than calling out to an external command, which you should avoid if at all possible.

Comment: Are you sure nginx is the right group&user? Usually it's www-data but that's on the debian systems I use. Not sure of its different on rhel

Comment: Thanks  everyone for taking the time to respond to my issue. It looks like doing what @AlexHowansky suggested is somewhat working because the output is all in one big line. What's the best way to format it into multi-line output?

Comment: @MisterG13 I've looked in various config files including /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf where the following are set to nginx: listen.owner = nginx listen.group = nginx and listen.acl_users = apache,nginx.